# Prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$.

I'm stucked here, i've approached the problem by looking at $\det(A-\lambda I)=0\iff\det(A^T-\lambda I)=0$. I tried some cases, and I can see it when the matrix is triangular since the main diagonal remains the same when $A$ is transposed, but this hasn't shown me a way to proceed. Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is an easier proof that avoids determinants:
First note that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ and use this to prove that $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^T$ is invertible. Thus
\begin{align*}
\lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of } A &⟺ (A - \lambda I) \text{ is not invertible}\\
&⟺ (A - \lambda I)^T \text{ is not invertible}\\
&⟺ A^T - \lambda I \text{ is not invertible}\\
&⟺\lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of } A^T.
\end{align*}

Comment: Classic Axler move!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Professor Axler.  So glad to see you here!  And thanks for the book!  Cheers!

Comment: This answer just made my day!

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**: Prove that $\det(A^T) = \det A$ for all square matrices $A$.

**Step 2**: Prove that $(A-\lambda I)^T = A^T - \lambda I$.